# it ok return 200 with notfound function and suspese?

Tags: next.js, http-status-code-404, react-suspense

when I use Suspense with fetch data and the response is not found. I use notFound() function of next/navigation, but HTTP response is 200, it seems good but is ok to SEO. Could it response 404?

Maybe this response a 404 o where is the 404 http response?